# Why net().get on success return empty string

Tags: java, android, playn

This is with playn.
I use this, only to try how it works:

```
net().get("http://google.com", new Callback<String>() 
 {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(String result) {
    drawResult(result);
   }                    
   @Override
   public void onFailure(Throwable cause) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     drawResult(cause.toString());
   }
 });
}
```

When i started this for Android or Java, onSuccess result is ok. When I started for html result is empty, where i wrong?
Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What does `net()` do and return? Please post the code of that method.

Answer (score 0):

That has to to with the Same origin policy for web browser: See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Workaround:
Execute your (google-)query first from your webserver. 
Then let your webserver communicate with your PlayN-html-client.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I still have same problem