# PlayN.Net returning empty String in HTML

Tags: playn

I can't understand the problem im having with PlayN.net. Maybe it's trivial, but since im new to web based stuff, I'm kinda stuck, so I hope someone here can enlighten me :)

My problem: I would like to acess a servlet from my game, it works, but only in java. Html gives me back an empty string.

Simple Servlet:

```java
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
      writer.println("test");
      writer.close();
   }
}
```

and simple call:

```sql
PlayN.net().get("http://localhost:8080/Test", new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                System.out.println("YAY "+result);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable cause) {
                System.out.println("BUH");
            }
        });
```

So like I said, java prints  "YAY test", HTML prints "YAY" and I cannot figure out why.
I tried running the servlet on an other server (not localhost) but the same reaction.

Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the browser (HTML) you have to work with the 'Same origin policy': See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Suggested solutions and work-arounds:

[Collaboration from PlayN client with server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053798/collaboration-from-playn-client-with-server)

[Why net().get on success return empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413576/why-net-get-on-success-return-empty-string)

Comment: Thankyou, it was like an epiphany, as I finaly understood :)